# Sort function in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
use warnings;

my @a = (1, 11, 3, 5, 21, 9, 10);

my @b = sort @a;

print "@b";
```

> Output: 1 10 11 21 3 5 9

Codepad link: http://codepad.org/Fvhcf3eP

I guess the [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#sort-SUBNAME-LIST) function is not taking the array's elements as an integer. That is why the output is not:

> 1 3 5 9 10 11 21

Is it?

How can I get the above result as output?

Comment: A FAQ link that is not half-broken (at this time): *[How do I sort an array by (anything)?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-sort-an-array-by-(anything)?)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default implementation of Perl's [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function is to sort values as strings. To perform numerical sorting:

```
my @a = sort {$a <=> $b} @b;
```

The linked page shows other examples of how to sort case-insensitively, in reverse order (descending), and so on.

You can create explicit subroutines to prevent duplication:

```
sub byord { $a <=> $b };
...
@a = sort byord @b;
```

This is functionally equivalent to the first example using an anonymous subroutine.

Comment: Useless guff inserted by another user has been removed.

Comment: Isn't there a potential conflict between `@a` and `$a`? E.g., what if you wanted to get the length of `@a`? Yes, @a is in the question, but perhaps elaborate on this?

Answer (score 7):

You are correct. So just tell Perl to treat it as an integer like below.

#### File *foop.pl*

```
use warnings;

my @a = (1, 11, 3, 5, 21, 9, 10);

my @b = sort {$a <=> $b} @a;

print "@b";
```

#### Run

```
perl foop.pl
1 3 5 9 10 11 21
```

Answer (score 6):

Provide a custom comparison function (comparing numerically):

```
sort {$a <=> $b} @array;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a numerical sort:

```
@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @not_sorted
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [spaceship operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison#Spaceship_operator): `sort { $a <=> $b } @a`

Comment: Programming Perl defines it as the spaceship operator, but it also mentions Star Wars, so I guess Tie Fighter is allowed too

Answer (score 4):

```
@b = sort { $a <=> $b } @a;
```

Is numerical

Answer (score 3):

Guessing is the wrong approach. If you don't understand sort, look it up: *[sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)*

```
my @b = sort{$a <=> $b} @a;
```