# How can I sort a Perl hash on values and order the keys correspondingly (in two arrays maybe)?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, perl-hash

In Perl, I want to sort the keys of a hash by value, numerically:

```
{
  five => 5
  ten => 10
  one => 1
  four => 4
}
```

producing two arrays:

```
(1,4,5,10) and (one, four, five, ten)
```

And then I want to normalize the values array such that the numbers are sequential:

```
(1,2,3,4)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First sort the keys by the associated value. Then get the values (e.g. by using a hash slice).

```
my @keys = sort { $h{$a} <=> $h{$b} } keys(%h);
my @vals = @h{@keys};
```

Or if you have a hash reference.

```
my @keys = sort { $h->{$a} <=> $h->{$b} } keys(%$h);
my @vals = @{$h}{@keys};
```

Comment: That was easy. Sometimes it's difficult to come up with those nice shortcuts. Thanks ikegami.

Comment: You can see more info in [sort function in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454744/sort-function-in-perl/6454804#6454804)

Answer (score 3):

```
my ( @nums, @words );
do { push @nums,  shift @$_; 
     push @words, shift @$_; 
   }
    foreach sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } 
            map  { [ $h->{ $_ }, $_ ] } keys %$h
   ;
```

Comment: @Moni, it works quite well, written the way it is. if you need `%h` then it's just `keys %h` and `$h{ $_ }` in the map.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's best to show rather than tell...

```
%results = (Paul=>87, Ringo=>93, John=>91, George=>97);

#display the results in ascending key (alphabetical) order
print "key ascending...\n";
foreach $key ( sort { $a cmp $b } keys %results ){
    print "$key=>$results{$key}\n";
}

print "\n";

# display the results in descending key (alphabetical) order
print "key descending...\n";
foreach $key ( sort { $b cmp $a } keys %results ){
    print "$key=>$results{$key}\n";
}

print "\n";

# display the results in descending value (numerical) order
print "value ascending...\n";
foreach $key ( sort { $results{$a} <=> $results{$b} } keys %results ){
    print "$key=>$results{$key}\n";
}

print "\n";

# display the results in ascending value (numerical) order
print "value descending...\n";
foreach $key ( sort { $results{$b} <=> $results{$a} } keys %results ){
    print "$key=>$results{$key}\n";
}
```