# How could I sort this hash array?

Tags: perl

I would like to sort alphabetically the content of `%hash{'name'}` maintaining the correlation of the other elements of `@{$hash{$keys}}`.

How can I do that?

```
my %hash = (
    date => [
        qw(
            2018/01/12
            2018/03/01
            2018/03/20
            2018/04/04
        )
    ],
    time => [
        qw(
            03:00:02
            01:00:01
            00:24:39
            11:33:33            
        )
    ],
    name => [
        qw(
            jerry
            tom
            micky
            agata            
        )
    ]
);
```

Desired Output:

```
date;time;name
2018/04/04;11:33:33;agata
2018/01/12;03:00:02;jerry
2018/03/20;00:24:39;micky
2018/03/01;01:00:01;tom
```

I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please include the expected output, and tell us if you've tried anything already. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I Haven't try to do it, because online i've found only sort of key list :( or sort of a single array. Maybe is it not possible to do it in perl? :(

Comment: You're not a software developer, are you? Don't give up like that. Everything is possible in pretty much any language. In this case, the language doesn't really have to do with the solution. This is a hard problem. Your data structure is not ideal. If you transpose your data into a different structure, the problem gets a lot simpler.

Comment: So your desired output is a CSV file. Maybe your input is CSV as well? That would make things A LOT easier. How did you get your `%hash`? Think about lines, not columns.

Comment: Thanks for your spur :). my input file isn't a csv. I manipulate a log and i push $date, $time and $name into my %hash:   
push @{ $hash{'date'} }, $date;            
push @{ $hash{'time'} }, $time;           
push @{ $hash{'name'} }, $name;

Comment: But it's all in one line at the time you read it? Why have you made the decision to use columns?

Comment: I've edited your question to show the data structure the way it actually is from what I gather from your description. You can also get something similar by using `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash`. That should help you see why I am going on about columns and rows. :)

Comment: You've made everything much more difficult by separating the columns. Instead, use `push @data, { date => $date, time => $time, name => $name }`

Comment: @Borodin you're spoiling my teaching moment :D I was working up on that so they'd figure it out themselves ;)

Comment: @simbabque: Your moment passed an hour ago!

Comment: @Borodin I guess you're right.

Comment: With the response time of the OP it's a bit like mail chess.

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit slow ... :(

Comment: No worries, this is not a chat. It's your task that needs solving, not ours. So have you looked over our comments? Please answer my question: _why did you decide to use columns, and not lines?_

Comment: @simbabque for columns, do you mean hashes ?

Comment: By _columns_ I mean putting each type of information (like _name_ and _date_) into its own array inside of the hash key. That's like putting it in columns in an Excel table. Why did you do that? What was your thought process?

Comment: @simbabque I chose this solution because I would like to do another sort order by date in the script. With key reference it will be more smart....(in my opinion)

Comment: No, on the contrary. Like this the different values are unrelated to each other.

Comment: @Borodin I might have gotten my moment after all. :)

Comment: @simbabque: Hooray!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I chose this solution because I would like to do another sort order by date in the script. With key reference it will be more smart...

This is the core part of your problem. Your thinking is correct, but you implemented it in the wrong way. That's what has put you into this corner now.

Let's take a look at your data first. You said it's a log file, so it's line-based. I've made this format up.

```
On 2018/01/12 at 03:00:02 user jerry did stuff.
On 2018/03/01 at 01:00:01 user tom did stuff.
On 2018/03/20 at 00:24:39 user micky did stuff.
On 2018/04/04 at 11:33:33 user agata did stuff.
```

And your expected output is a CSV file. Again, this is line-based.

> ```
> date;time;name
> 2018/04/04;11:33:33;agata
> 2018/01/12;03:00:02;jerry
> 2018/03/20;00:24:39;micky
> 2018/03/01;01:00:01;tom
> ```

So it stands to reason that the structure you want the data to be in is still line-based.

When you want to sort this data by any of the columns, you are sorting **rows** based on values in the columns. So you really want to store the rows, in a way that makes it easy to access the values of each individual column for that row. This becomes especially clear once you look at it in a spreadsheet.

[image: screenshot of libreoffice spreadsheet with the example data]

Each of the columns is one value of a row. So let's do that.

```
my @events; # or something like that
while (my $row = <$log_fh>) {
    my ( $date, $time, $name ) = parse_row($row); # we don't care about this implementation

    push @events, {
        date => $date,
        time => $time,
        name => $name,
    };
}
```

Now we have this data structure (which I've output with [Data::Printer](https://p3rl.org/Data::Printer)).

```
[
    [0] {
        date   "2018/01/12",
        name   "jerry",
        time   "03:00:02"
    },
    [1] {
        date   "2018/03/01",
        name   "tom",
        time   "01:00:01"
    },
    [2] {
        date   "2018/03/20",
        name   "micky",
        time   "00:24:39"
    },
    [3] {
        date   "2018/04/04",
        name   "agata",
        time   "11:33:33"
    }
]
```

As you can see, there is one hash reference per line, and that contains a key for the date, one for the time and one for the name.

Now we can sort on any of the keys inside of those structures. [That's easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10901084/1331451).

```
my @events_by_name = sort { $a->{name} cmp $b->{name} } @events;
my @events_by_date = sort { $a->{date} cmp $b->{date} } @events;
my @events_by_time = sort { $a->{time} cmp $b->{time} } @events;
```

And then you can produce CSV files for each of them.

```
open my $fh, '>', 'events_by_name.csv' or die $!;
foreach my $event (@events_by_name) {
    print $fh join ';', $event->{name}, $event->{date}, $event->{time};
    print $fh "\n";
}
close $fh;
```

Or you could iterate with the number of events, open several at the same time and only loop once.

```
open my $fh_name, '>', 'events_by_name.csv' or die $!;
open my $fh_date, '>', 'events_by_date.csv' or die $!;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @events_by_name; $i++) {
    print $fh_name join(
         ';', 
         @events_by_name->[$i]->{name}, 
         @events_by_name->[$i]->{date}, 
         @events_by_name->[$i]->{time},
    ); 
    print $fh_name "\n";

    print $fh_date join(
         ';', 
         @events_by_name->[$i]->{name}, 
         @events_by_name->[$i]->{date}, 
         @events_by_name->[$i]->{time},
    ); 
    print $fh_date "\n";
}
close $fh_name;
close $fh_date;
```

You can further shorten this by using another loop.

```
open my $fh_name, '>', 'events_by_name.csv' or die $!;
open my $fh_date, '>', 'events_by_date.csv' or die $!;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @events_by_name; $i++) {
    foreach my $fh ($fh_name, $fh_date) {
        print $fh join(
             ';', 
             @events_by_name->[$i]->{name}, 
             @events_by_name->[$i]->{date}, 
             @events_by_name->[$i]->{time},
        ); 
        print $fh "\n";
    }
}
close $fh_name;
close $fh_date;
```

As you can see, it makes a lot more sense to keep the structure line-based when you are dealing with lines.

Comment: How can i kiss you right now? You'r post it's so clear <3

Comment: @Perler no need for that. Happy to help. I tried to focus on the actual, underlying problem rather than the immediate question. Often beginners don't really know what question to ask. That's one of the many skills you will develop over time. // You might want to check [ask] to see what to do if there's an answer that resolves your question. :)

Comment: @simbabque i've put your answer as resolution :) . For print my sorted array of keys, what have i to correct?

print "-- Date --|--- Time ---|-- Name --\n"; #HEAD of List
for (my $i=0; $i <= ($#events_by_user); $i++) {
 say join ';',$events_by_user{'date'}[$i],$events_by_user{'time'}[$i],$events_by_user{'name'}[$i];
}

Comment: @perler you've got it the wrong way around. I'll update the answer and add that.

Comment: @simbabque, thanks i've compile the script and it works perfectly <3