# Perl - Remove element from an array if already exist in another

Tags: arrays, perl

I've a question about perl embeded functions.
In your opinion, "map" function could help me for made a pop of all elements in an array, if already exist it in another array?

These are the arrays:

**Array named OLDER_EVENTS:**

```
my @older_events = (
    surname => [
        qw(
            red
            brown
            simpson
            donald         
        )
    ],
    date => [
        qw(
            2018/02/14
            2018/03/09
            2018/05/01
            2018/08/02
        )
    ],
    time => [
        qw(
            01:00:52
            01:06:41
            03:24:31
            19:14:31            
        )
    ]
);
```

**ARRAY NAMED NEW ELEMENTS:**

```
my @new_events = (
    surname => [
        qw(
            simpson
            donald         
            blanco
            ernald
        )
    ],
    date => [
        qw(
            2018/03/09
            2018/08/02
            2018/08/01
            2018/08/14
        )
    ],
    time => [
        qw(
            03:24:31
            19:14:31            
            00:03:16
            09:21:45
        )
    ]
);
```

In new events, last two entries are new, so, I would pop elements 1 and 2 from @new_events because it already exist in @older_events

How could I do it, with a smart solution?

Have I to use a third array, or, could I pop it from @older_events?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: In my opinion you have to use a third array, without use map function

Comment: @clarkseth but if I use a third array, performance of my script would worsen.. is it not possible to use a pop into @new_events?

Comment: This looks familiar. Have we not had a similar question a few days ago?

Comment: You are talking about an array and a hash here. Your data structures are NOT similar, and are not really useful to hold the information you want to convey. I take it that you mean to say that _simpson_'s date is `2018/03/09` and time is `03:24:21`.

Comment: Please clarify: Is the question about removing element 0 and 1 from `@{ $new_events{surname} }` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51059931/1331451 for an explanation of why your data structure is strange.

Comment: @simbabque my older question was about sort -u command ("Remove multiple duplicate lines from a file")

Comment: No, not your question. But the data structure you are using looks almost exactly like the one in the question I linked above. Are you reading a file by columns, not lines?

Comment: Then re-read my answer there please. You'll see it might not be the best idea to do it the way you are doing. Explain where you are getting your data from and I'll help you structure it to make your life easier. :)

Comment: It's especially interesting to know what else you want to do with the data. If you only want to check for duplicates, you can generate an ID for each row based on a  digest of the whole row (or even just a concatenation of all fields) and put them in a lookup hash like that. Since you've mentioned speed, that would make sense. But then speed shouldn't be an issue unless you have millions of records and are running on a Raspberry Pie.

Comment: @simbabque yes, I've start my script from it "stackoverflow.com/q/51059931/1331451" because it was very similar to mine. I'm reading a file by line, not column and I have to push elements into array. I've a history file named history.log so I use it for load "date,time,surname" elements into @ older_events and I have a current log file named anagr_sysdate.log that load each elements (date, time and surname) into @ new_events, using the same keys.

Comment: I have to made a diff from @ older_events and @ new_events, for storing only new rows, because new_events will contain some elements already present into @ older_events and I don't want to have duplicate at the end of my elaboration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176157/discussion-between-simbabque-and-thomas-anowez).

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you're using arrays for key-value pairs. This is not useful.

```
my %older_events = @older_events;
my %newer_events = @newer_events;
```

Secondly, your want to perform operations on records, but your data isn't organized into records.

```
my @older_events =
   map {
      +{
         surname => $older_events->{ surname }[$_],
         date    => $older_events->{ date    }[$_],
         time    => $older_events->{ time    }[$_],
      }
   }
      0..$#{ $older_events->{surname} };

my @newer_events =
   map {
      +{
         surname => $newer_events->{ surname }[$_],
         date    => $newer_events->{ date    }[$_],
         time    => $newer_events->{ time    }[$_],
      }
   }
      0..$#{ $newer_events->{surname} };
```

Thirdly, we need a quick way to lookup if an event is in `@older_events`.

```
sub key { join "\0", @{ $_[0] }{qw( surname date time )} }

my %older_event_by_key =
   map { key($_) => $_ }
      @older_events;
```

Finally, we can grep

```
@newer_events =
   grep { !$old_event_by_key{ key($_) } }
      @newer_events;
```

Comment: so, is it better if I push my elements, not into an array, but into an hash?
My array loader is push @newer_events, { date => "$y/$m/$d", time => $time, surname => $surname}; # Array loader

Comment: That's NOT what you do according to your question. If it is was you actually do, skip the first two steps of my answer (since they transform the data from the structure you posted in your question into the structure you posted in the comment).